# How to Offset\Distribute EVENLY with PBR in Blender 2.8x?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor

this my first question here and yes i'm a beginner in Blender especially in PBR.

So i'm trying to create a conveyor belt close to what you see in factories lines or airports, and I started with a simple cube (Default cube) and shaped it into a belt like you see in the pictures below.

Then I wanted to create vertical lines using the shader editor which then I can create an image from by baking it and then use it as diffuse map in Unity where then all I have to do is to just offset it (through time) the Y axis of the material in unity creating the effect of a working conveyor belt.

What I said above almost worked but I keep facing this issue, where **the lines are not evenly distributed**, they are sometimes close to each other and sometimes are far from each other **only on curved faces**. They are evenly distributed on the straight faces but the not of the curved faces.

From the pictures below you can see where that happen and also you can see that the belt is perfectly Unwrapped. The cube is just made of 64 faces and I didn't use any modifier on the cube.

**The lines i'm talking about are made like this:**

- Coordinate Texture Node > Mapping Node > Wave Texture Node > ColorRamp Node
- Where i'm using the UV output of the Coordinate texture and in
  the Mapping node I set the rotation to 90 on X and 45 on Y to make
  the the lines vertical and in the ColorRamp I set the factor to a very small
  value to make the lines thin.

***Please download the blender file if you don't know what i'm talking, it's a very simple model. You can download it from github [Here](https://github.com/rashiddev93/Blender). I created it in Blender 2.81a.***

[image: Belt + UV]

[image: Shader editor]

[image: Lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the UVs of your mesh so that they are spaced evenly according to their dimensions. Since your mesh will map nicely onto a 2D plane. Blender can do this for you very easily.

What you had was close, but not mathematically perfect.

The best way to do it would first be to mark a seam on your mesh that will tell blender where it can start mapping, then a normal U unwrap will work (keeping the dimensions of the faces consistent). See GIF

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, please see my other question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161480/how-to-uv-unwrap-this-simple-object